# Why am I able to create a compound index with a hashed field within?

Tags: mongodb

According to MongoDB docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-hashed/, I shouldn't be able to create a compound index with a hashed field within.

However, I've tried the following.

`db.collection.createIndex({"hash_this_field": "hashed"})`

And right after creating that index, tried with this one.

`db.collection.createIndex({"date": 1, "hash_this_field": 1})`

And it was just there! No problems at all when creating it, even changing the other (if that matters).

Note that I'm running a local MongoDB version `4.0.3 Community`, hope that can shed some light if this major allows to do so?

Comment: The field content is not hashed itself, it's just the index. The documentation in fact  states *"You may not create compound indexes that have hashed index fields or specify a unique constraint on a hashed index; however, you can create both a hashed index and an ascending/descending (i.e. non-hashed) index on the same field:"*

Comment: To be clear that means this is **NOT** allowed `createIndex({ "field1": "hashed", "field2": 1 })` And neither is `createIndex({ "field1": "hashed" },{ "unique": true })`. However what you actually did and are alluding to as a *bug* is actually exactly what the second statement in the docs ( after "however" ) is saying you can of course do. So nothing in this means you cannot have more than one index referencing a particular field in the documents of the collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a fast response @NeilLunn! I was so confused with this...